# Using POST to sign up in a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, post, postman

I'm currently working on a project for school. I am building both a backend and a frontend application. I have the POST working on the backend and i've tested it with postman and it posts and saves it in MongoDB. How would I get the post working if its on a browser? I have a form with firstname, lastname, email, and password. How do I post on the browser? Is it possible to post on live server?

I tried hosting it on heroku and it didn't work. I tried hosting on react but it works but I would rather do it on liveserver if its possible.

here is my html file for registering.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Register</title>
    <style>
        html{
            background-color:hsl(60, 20%, 80%);



        }
        input[type=text],
        input[type=password] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            border: black 1.5px solid;
            background: #f1f1f1;
        }

        input[type=text]:focus,
        input[type=password]:focus {
            background-color: #ddd;
            outline: none;
        }


        button {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }

        button:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .cancelbtn {
            padding: 14px 20px;
            background-color: #f44336;
        }

        .cancelbtn,
        .signupbtn {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;

        }



        .clearfix::after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: table;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <p>Please fill in this form to create your accout.</p>
        <label for="firstname"><b>First Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstname" required>

        <label for="lastname"><b>Last Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lastname" required>

        <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

        <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </form>


</body>

</html>
```

here is my post method for the back end.

```
router.post('/', sanitizeBody, async (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.sanitizeBody);
      let password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltrounds)
    new User({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        password,
        email: req.body.email,
        isStaff: req.body.isStaff
    }).save().then(result => {
        res.status(201).send(result);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.send(err);
    })

  })
```

I expect to post on the html page rather than posting it on postman. I would like it to post on the index.html live server when I hit submit.

Comment: heroku can be a challenge as there file system is a bit strange.  If you want to host live try something like 000webhost.  An alternative would be to launch apache tomcat as your local server and debug on your home machine.

Comment: It's not possible to post from live server and then when I post it sends to Mongo?

Comment: please rephrase your question so it makes sense. If Mongo is installed on the server you should be able to access it from the backend.  Are you using node for the backend?